# Parse column from sql database and bind to specific column in grid

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net

I have 1 column of strings called Colors (`Colors nchar(10) NOT NULL`) in a SQL table. The colors can be Red, Blue, Green, Yellow or Orange. In the same table, I have a column called names (`Names nchar(20) NOT NULL`) which holds names of children. I have a grid in my ASP.NET application with five columns for each of the colors (Red, Blue, Green, Yellow or Orange) and another column for the names. Each row in my grid represents a child, and for each child, the favorite color of the child should be marked with a boolean. Is there an easy way to do this?

Not looking for super specific code--just the framework of the for loop through each of the children's names. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that by "marked as a boolean," you want to use checkbox controls in your grid to show true / false values for each color column, you can try something like this:

An example GridView control (I'm not including data-binding code for brevity):

```
<asp:GridView ID="childGrid" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false">
        <Columns>
               <asp:BoundField DataField="Name" />
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Red">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:CheckBox ID="Red" runat="server"  />
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
               <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Green">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:CheckBox ID="Green" runat="server"  />
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
               <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Yellow">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:CheckBox ID="Yellow" runat="server"  />
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
               <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Orange">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:CheckBox ID="Orange" runat="server" />
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
        </Columns>

</asp:GridView>
```

In the code-behind class:

```
void ctlGrid_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {

        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {
            DataRowView item = (DataRowView)e.Row.DataItem;
            //get value of Color from the bound data
            string color = item["Color"].ToString();
            //make sure that the casing (i.e., lower, upper or proper) of each checkbox ID matches what's in the DB
            ((CheckBox)e.Row.FindControl(color)).Checked = true;

        }

    }
```

**Important:** In this example, I am using a simple convention, which is to assume that the ID of each of the CheckBox controls in the GridView matches a value in the Color column of your "Children" table (case-sensitive match). Obviously, you can modify the ID naming scheme by using a specific casing (e.g. lower, upper or proper) and modify the code-behind code I've provided to account for the specific casing.

Answer (score 0):

One approach is the 'materialize' the colors into boolean columns in the result set.  **Warning:** This may not scale well if your list of colors gets large - but the concept is common.

Given

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.Children ( ChildID INT Identity,
                            Name    NVARCHAR(20)
                    ,       Color   NCHAR(10)
                    )
```

and some sample data:

```
INSERT INTO dbo.Children (Name, Color) Values ('Ted', 'Red')
INSERT INTO dbo.Children (Name, Color) Values ('Alice', 'Green')
```

the pattern looks like this:

```
SELECT  c.ChildID
,   c.Name
,   CAST( CASE WHEN c.Color = 'Red' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END as BIT) as LovesRed
,   CAST( CASE WHEN c.Color = 'Green' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END as BIT) as LovesGreen
-- ... one for each color
FROM dbo.Children c
```

I also realize I changed your column names to singular (color instead of colors)...because that follows a pretty ingrained standard.

You can then bind `LovesGreen` and `LovesRed` (etc) to your grid in a very straightforward manner.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
  protected void dgvSearch_RowDataBound(object sender, System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Row.RowType == System.Web.UI.WebControls.DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {
            string myVal = e.Row.Cells[1].Text;
            if (myVal == "Red")
            {
                e.Row.Cells[1].Text = "True";
            }
        }
    }
```

You would have to loop through the cells on each row, but the example above shows you how to select the cells and set the text. Hope this is along the lines of what your looking for.